# Eregi to preg_replace change for php 5.3 compatibility

Tags: php, regex, deprecated, pcre, posix-ere

I have this line in one of my scripts and its throwing a deprecated error.

```
 eregi_replace( '\.([a-z]{3,4})$', "-{$width}x{$height}.\\1", $src );
```

Can someone show me how to turn this into `preg_replace` and tell me why and which bits of it need to change so I can learn for future changes? I have had a go myself but where this bit of code is means its really hard to test!!

Is it as simple as purely replacing the `eregi_replace` with `preg_replace`?

I hate regular expressions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [delimiters](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters) like `/` and the [*i* modifier](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers):

```
/\.([a-z]{3,4})$/i
```

So:

```
preg_replace('/\.([a-z]{3,4})$/i', "-{$width}x{$height}.\\1", $src);
```

See this [manual page for the differences between POSIX ERE and PCRE](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.posix).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, need to work out how to test it now :)